# How do you decide the feature scope of event receiver?

Tags: event-receivers, feature-scope

We have event receivers for List, List field, List items, Web, Site and List email.

How do we decide the feature scope of the event receivers?

Is it best practice to set it to sitecollection or web application?

Answer (score 3):

Generally scope should be Web because Event Receivers are triggered by certain events on either a SPWeb, SPList or SPListItem. We can categorize SharePoint events in two different categories: by the “level” which fires the event (site, list, item), and by the type of the event (synchronous and asynchronous).

Again depends what you want to achieve... scope can be site also For example : if your feature is scoped at the Site level for List event receiver , the receiver will bind to all list instances in the site collection.

Comment: the question is specifically regarding which scopes are applicable to event receivers and your answer does not relate to this.

Answer (score -1):

Event Receiver Feature must be set as **Web** Scope..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454835.aspx

Comment: Web or Site is the correct scopes

Comment: Site Scope will bind to More than One List if available in more than one web.

Comment: @RobertLindgren how do you decide web or site feature-scope?

Comment: See @priyankagupta 's answer. It dependes on the granualarity you want (do you want to control it per web, or do you want it on all webs in a site collection)